# How to take out extreme event annually from data that includes leap years

Tags: matlab

I have program (matlab) which calculate an extreme event annually for whole 95 years but this program works only for those who does not include leap years.

e.g. data size is 20x22x34675(lon,lat,time)(365*95) but I want to calculate extreme event annually for those data who include leap years (it mean 365 Or 366 then 365 Or 366 ....each separate years) then what will be change in this program for doing this?

My data size is `prec_all_years`: 20x22x34698(lon,lat,time)(365*95+23 = 34698).  This is daily data.

```
prec_all_years = prec_all_years*86400; % rainfall in mm/day

bins = [64.5 124.5 244.5 Inf];

% Reshape into lat/lon/day/year, and bin over 3rd dimension (days)

counts = histc(reshape(prec_all_years,20,22,365,95),bins,3);

% Extract the counts for each of the 3 categories

hr = squeeze(counts(: , : , 1 , : ));

vhr = squeeze(counts(: , : , 2 , : ));

ehr = squeeze(counts(: , : , 3 , : ));

% Extract a region

xe = 13:20; ye = 11:16;% xe is x for east,ye is y for east

% Extract counts for each category

count_hr_east = sum(reshape(hr(xe , ye , : ) , [] , 95 ));

count_vhr_east = sum(reshape(vhr(xe , ye , : ) , [] , 95 ));

count_ehr_east = sum(reshape(ehr(xe , ye , : ) , [] , 95 ));
```

Comment: use `datenum` and `datestr` to convert time to actual year. Use pivot year argument.

Comment: shai Sir i can not understand.can you write here code for this?.please sir help me,thank you